# unknown column in where clause, but I've already verified

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm struggling with this simple line of SQL...

Running it keeps giving me the error: `Error: Unknown column 'comics' in 'where clause'`.

This would normally be an easy fix... just go check to make sure "comics" exists as an entry in column "table_name". But I've already checked that...

[image]

I don't see anything wrong with my SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND table_name = $table AND imgid = $imgid";
```

EDIT:

Btw, I've already tried it with quotes:

```
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND table_name = '$table' AND imgid = $imgid";
```

But that throws the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in C:\wamp\www\HTwS\scripts\likecounter.php on line 40
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `table_name` is a string, and must therefore be single-quoted in the query. Failing to quote it as a string value, MySQL assumes that the supplied unquoted `$table` is a column identifier.

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND table_name = '$table' AND imgid = $imgid";
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

If `$imgid` is also a non-numeric value you'll need to quote that one as well.

We assume it has already been properly filtered against SQL injection, if it is the result of user input. I'll note, since the update includes MySQLi-specific code, that you really ought to be doing this [as a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than a constructed string call to `mysqli::query()`.

```
// Recommended to do this with  a prepared statement.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = ? AND table_name = ? AND imgid = ?");
if ($stmt) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $table, $imgid);
  $stmt->execute();
  // Bind results, fetch, etc...
}
```

---

#### Edit after question update and comment:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

The error message implies that you have attempted to access the MySQLi result property `num_rows` as a *method call* with `()` rather than a property.  You should be using:

```
$result->num_rows
```

... instead of

```
$result->num_rows()
```

Comment: See my edit above, I meant to include that... I've already tried this and it throws the error above

Comment: I've also tried it without the quotes on $imgid, and single quotes around $table, but it throws that error

Comment: Wow, I should really try reading the actual error messages sometimes... that was the fix! haha thank you!